# The database is updated with inserted data but the error appears

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a shared view `"_header.cshtml"` containing bootstrap modal from signin/up purpose.That being said i need a controller for the shared view.I did some study and came up with solution.It works(data is inserted into database) but at the same time displays error.

This is my `_layout.cshtml`

```
 <header>
        @Html.Action("header","RegUser");
    </header>
```

And here goes my controller `RegUserController.cs`

```
public ActionResult header()
{
  // var mod = new RegisterTbl();
    return PartialView("_header");
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult header(RegisterTbl rt)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (IsnsEntities1 sns = new IsnsEntities1())
        {
            sns.RegisterTbls.Add(rt);
            sns.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            rt = null;
            ViewBag.Message = "successfully registered";
        }
    }
    return PartialView(rt);

}
```

And i get this error 
`Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.`

Comment: It probably means an infinite loop for rendering...

Comment: can you please help me find it..i am trying to figure out the error all day long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the post action, you are returning only model and not specifying View. So, by convention, it will try to search for view named "header". Which it will not be able to find.

Please change `return PartialView(rt);` to `return PartialView("_header",rt);`